# How to mock dry-rb (used inf Reform contract) validation configure method

Tags: rspec, trailblazer, reform, dry-rb

My problem is that I want to mock my custom validation method that returns some data from DB ( list of ids - to check if given id is in my DB ).

So less talk, more code:
in my Newsletter::Contract::Create class I have

```
validation do
  configure do
    config.messages_file = "config/error_messages.yml"
    def publisher_exists?(value)
      Publisher.where(id: value).present?
    end
  end
  required(:publisher_id).filled(:publisher_exists?)
end
```

And in test, I try to run

```
expect(Newsletter::Contract::Create).to receive(:publisher_exists?).and_return(true)
```

but obviously i receive

```
Newsletter::Contract::Create does not implement: publisher_exists?
```

So the question is what object calls for my custom validate methods, so I can mock it?;]

Answer (score 0):

So far what i understand is that there probably is some eval/anynoumus classes, so instead of mocking this method, i will stub AR that is used inside of method.
    `expect(Publisher).to receive_message_chain(:where, :present?).and_return(true)`